# Counting unique lines with single select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have these two tables, one with duplicates and second one with data that is supposed to be unique. The thing is that some of the duplicates were not detected in the first select, and I cannot change it. New select must be used. To divide duplicates from unique data I made this simple select:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(Ref) as number
FROM [DB1].[DBO].[TB1] t
     FULL outer join [DB1].[DBO].[DUPLICATES] d
     ON t.Ref = d.Ref and t.ID = d.ID
     WHERE DUP_DATE = "2020-06-11"
GROUP BY t.Ref, t.ID,
HAVING COUNT(t.Ref) = 1
```

This is suposed to give me back the data that has no duplicated information in column Ref. While trying to exe this select it gives me back this error:

> Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

As I'm not familiar with T-SQL I would be grateful for any support provided. I tried some of the previously proposed solutions (here on stack), yet none of them worked for me.

EDIT: Here is the sample:

```
TB1
| REF    | DUP_DATE  |
| ------ | --------- |
| 36676  | Chicago   |
| 24671  | Singapur  |
| 89783  | Rotterdam |
| 85476  | Warsaw    |
| 12567  | Sydney    |
| 98437  | NYC       |

TB Duplicates
| REF   | DUP_DATE    |
| ----- | ----------- |
| 24671 | Mexico City |
| 89783 | Oxford      |
```

The output I want to get:

```
| REF   | DUP_DATE | Number |
| ----- | -------- | ------ |
| 36676 | Chicago  |    1   |
| 85476 | Warsaw   |    1   |
| 12567 | Sydney   |    1   |
| 98437 | NYC      |    1   |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  As a note:  `full join` is very rarely used.

Comment: you want to use HAVING

Comment: Your `FULL OUTER JOIN` isn't going to be a `FULL OUTER JOIN` anyway. Due to your `WHERE` it's an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Weird to show the "Number" column, since the very existence of a row implies Number will be `1` for every record.

Comment: Also: not sure there's enough data here. The sample should include examples of outliers.

Comment: Ok so you want to exclude all records in TB Duplicates from the query is that correct?  What causes Singapur and Rotterdam to be excluded from your results?  Also you said there were duplicates missed in your first select but your example doesn't show any duplicates.

Comment: Also `DUP_DATE` is in *both* your objects, however, you don't qualify it so the above would error, telling you that the column `DUP_DATE` is ambiguous.

Comment: And is Dupe date a city name or a date value? Because it's used in both ways. These things may seem pedantic to you, but computers are the ultimate pedantic communicators. If you can't learn that kind of precision in how you approach code and talking about code, you'll struggle to be effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `*` with `GROUP BY`. Limit the `SELECT` clause to items used in the `GROUP BY` clause and aggregate/grouping functions like `SUM()` and `AVG()`.

Also, the `COUNT(t.Ref) = 1` expression, in addition to the type, should probably be in a `HAVING` clause and the double quotes around the date literal don't mean what you think in SQL.

Finally, this is the smallest of nitpicks, but date-only literals in Sql Server should use the *unseparated* variant of ISO8601.

```
SELECT t.Ref, t.ID, COUNT(Ref) as number
FROM [DB1].[DBO].[TB1] t
FULL JOIN [DB1].[DBO].[DUPLICATES] d
     ON t.Ref = d.Ref and t.ID = d.ID
WHERE DUP_DATE = '20200611'
GROUP BY t.Ref, t.ID
HAVING COUNT(t.Ref) = 1
```

Comment: You can use * with group by, but all columns must either be part of the group by, or aggregate, so * just gets you the whole table, but slower.

Comment: @JaazCole If you're grouping by everything, so `*` is valid, you're unlikely to have a meaningful GROUP BY clause anymore, and there's almost certainly a mistake in the code, or in the schema that allowed that kind of duplicate record to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think `DUP_DATE` column should be `datetime` type however, it is look like a `varchar` column. That's why I have used `DUP_DATE` as  `Varchar`. Finally, here is a solution with exact output =>

```
DECLARE @TB1 Table (REF INT, DUP_DATE Varchar(50));
DECLARE @TBDuplicates Table (REF INT, DUP_DATE Varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES (36676,'Chicago');
INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES (24671,'Singapur');
INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES (89783,'Rotterdam');
INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES (85476,'Warsaw');
INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES (12567,'Sydney');
INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES (98437,'NYC');

INSERT INTO @TBDuplicates VALUES (24671,'Mexico City');
INSERT INTO @TBDuplicates VALUES (89783,'Oxford');

SELECT t.REF,t.DUP_DATE,COUNT(*) Number FROM @TB1 t
LEFT JOIN @TBDuplicates t1 ON t.REF=t1.REF
WHERE t1.REF IS NULL
GROUP BY  t.REF,t.DUP_DATE
ORDER BY t.DUP_DATE,t.REF
```